# TypeError when using tf.keras.layers.Reshape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

when building a model in Keras, I run into this error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got 8.0 of type 'float' instead.
```

The error occurs when initially building the model (as opposed to during execution), more specifically on the last line of this snippet:

```
    d_dense1 = Dense(
        ((IMAGE_SIZE/4)**2)*(n if vanilla_architecture else 3*n),
        input_shape = (h,),
        activation = "relu",
        name = name_prefix + "dense1"
    )(d_in)
    d_reshape1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(
        (IMAGE_SIZE/4, IMAGE_SIZE/4, (n if vanilla_architecture else 3*n)),
        name = name_prefix + "reshape1"
    )(d_dense1)
```

> Side note: I am using tf.keras.layers.Dense, IMAGE_SIZE is an integer, vanilla_architecture is a boolean, and n is an integer

Obviously the dense layer will pass along a tensor of floats because, well, it's a machine learning operation. The issue seems to be that Reshape requires a tensor of integers. I read the documentation but there is no information there.

Here are some things I've tried:

- using tf.reshape

  - Same issue
- using numpy reshape

  - Just plain doesn't work
- reading example code like like 54 of [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_acgan.py)

  - they seem to be doing the same thing as me but theirs works

The weird part is that it works just fine when using eager execution. I don't want to have eager execution enabled though because I want to use tensorboard.

Comment: How about `tf.cast(IMAGE_SIZE, tf.int32)`?

Comment: Probably because the division `IMAGE_SIZE/4` results in a float. As @KotaMori mentions maybe try casting it explicitly to an int using `tf.cast(IMAGE_SIZE/4, tf.int32)`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked, now I feel dumb haha

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use integer division in this line:

```
(IMAGE_SIZE//4, IMAGE_SIZE//4, (n if vanilla_architecture else 3*n)),
```

The type error was not due to the tensor but instead that IMAGE_SIZE/4 returned a float

Comment: To add to this answer: You can easily resolve this by an explicit cast to `integer` like so:
`(int(IMAGE_SIZE//4), int(IMAGE_SIZE//4, ...)`